# AndEngine Update Thread Works Slowly for Large sprites

Tags: android, andengine

I have created sprite with texture size of 2048X1024 and attached to my scene.
Things are going fine but problem is that when i attach any other sprite with scene it takes time to display. Without this larger sprite things are displayed without any note able delay.
As I attache this larger sprite other attachments start getting time to display
I am working on AndEngine
Please help if any one solved this kind of problem
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out why you would need an image of that size on your screen. The problem is that Android limits image sizes to around 1024 x 1024 so AndEngine is most likely swapping out the different images. Without seeing your code or knowing what you are trying to do, there's not much I can suggest. except to break your large image down into images smaller than 1024 x 1024. If you are doing a game and are using the image as a background I'd suggest looking into using a program called "Tiled" and loading it up in AndEndine using its TMXLoader. There is a tutorial on the AndEngine forum for this.